# Problems with a huge equation in math enviromental

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize, alignment, text

how are you?

I need a help: I have searched in many places for, in my opinion, try to solve a problem that occurs to me in math mode in my msc thesis.

I have to put these equations in same line:

```
\begin{align*}
    x=\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}{\sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\omega $3}^2}-\frac{3 \sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\omega $1}^2}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}\right)\\
   x &=\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \text{$\omega $1}^2}{2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\omega $3}^2}\\
   x &=\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \text{$\omega $1}^2}{2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2 \text{$\omega $3}^8 \sin ^2(\alpha )+108 \text{$\omega $1}^6 \text{$\omega $3}^6}+27 g \text{$\omega $3}^4 \sin (\alpha )}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2} \text{$\omega $3}^2}\\
   y &= 0
\end{align*}
```

But, when I tried to use commands such `\text{\footnotesize{}}`, `\scalebox{}{}`, I got problems.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone, please, help me with this? I'm using the Papeeria as online latex editor and TexStudio as offine editor.

Thank you so much.

The Wolfram Mathematica result is:
[image]

Comment: From what I saw, the terms inside the square root are all the same. Set a variable to this value (e.g. TSR) and write these equations using \sqrt{TSR}

Comment: Welcome! That is a big formula indeed. You can impose extra breaks before the minus sign, and perhaps indent next line with a `\quad`, but I would first ask if somebody really will read such a horrible formula. I would not. Maybe not setting it is the best thing to do, if possible.

Comment: These formulas shoowed in my question are, believe or not, the simplification of a ugliest formula ( I use the $Assumptions = omega1>0 && omega3>0 && g>=0 && alpha>=0; and \FullSimplify commands in Wolfram Mathematica).

Comment: I agree with michep. But if you need, try larger paper or landscape or at least show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to put these equations in [the] same line

The only way this is going to happen is if you substitute a symbol, say, "P", for the very long term

```
\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2\omega 3^8 \sin^2\alpha+108\omega 1^6\omega 3^6}+27 g\omega 3^4 \sin\alpha}
```

that occurs a total of six times.

The result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Put $P=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{729 g^2\omega 3^8 \sin^2\alpha+108\omega 1^6\omega 3^6}+27 g\omega 3^4 \sin\alpha}$ and $Q=\sqrt[3]{2}\omega 3^2$.
\begin{align*}
    x&=\frac{1}{3}\biggl(\frac{P}{Q} - \frac{3\sqrt[3]{2}\omega 1^2}{P}\biggr)\\
   x &=\frac{(1+i\sqrt{3})\omega 1^2}{2^{2/3} P} - \frac{(1-i\sqrt{3}) P}{6 Q}\\
   x &=\frac{(1-i\sqrt{3})\omega 1^2}{2^{2/3} P} - \frac{(1+i\sqrt{3}) P}{6 Q}\\
   y &= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this for sure.
Have a nice day.

Comment: @VictorPintoMscStudent - You're most welcome. Incidentally, is there a reason for writing `729` instead of `3^6`, and for writing `108` instead of `2^2 3^3`? Doing the prime factor representation would allow you to see that `729 g^2\omega 3^8` could be written more succinctly as `g^2\omega 3^{14}`. Likewise, `108\omega 1^6\omega 3^6` could be re-expressed as `\omega^2 2^2 3^9`, no?